# Display document styling variables

Tags: layout, variable

My tex-illiterate teacher wants to check the formatting of our submission (e.g: margins, fonts size, spacing, etc...)

Unlike WYSIWYG, it is not possible to select text and know its properies.

**Question**: what is an easy reliable way for my teacher to check I am following the formatting they require?

What I tried: `layouts` package, but it does not display other variables, such as the  font size, spacing... + it is not practical to check for each page in the document.

Comment: (1) Provide the source code, including comments of which lines set the required format. e.g.: `\documentclass[12pt]{article} % this set the font size to 12pt` and  teach him to compile it. Include also  some text  in every  page as  `This text have now a font size of {\makeatletter\f@size} pt and line skips of  \the\baselineskip\ and spaces between paragraphs of  \the\parskip\ ...` , or (2) Give him a printed version of the PDF and a  good ruler, or (3) Pandoc is your friend. Make your teacher happy a just submit a  Word version.  If I was in your shoes, I would choose the last  option.

Comment: @fran Thanks for the reply. The problem is that I don't set any of these manually. I just use`\documentclass[stu]{apa7}` and LaTeX takes care of everything. I was thinking about Pandoc, too. But even for me as a LaTeX user, I want to know what variables does every document style uses without referring to its source code (e.g: what are all properties in subheading that APA uses?: centered, bold, etc...). Word is convenient in just selecting the text and knowing everything about it.

Comment: As said above, you can always print much information about document settings, as current lengths, counters (e.g., commands like  `\the\parskip` or `\thesection`) or font size, and/or show this information in the console and log file (e.g., end your text with  `\typeout{Paragraphs skips are  of \the\parskip}` but LaTeX has too many settings and the question is too general.